# How to create a ViewPager with 3 Fragments inside a Fragment on the same page?

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I want to create an application to **display 3 different fragments inside a fragment using ViewPager**. The fragments will look like in the picture shown down below:

[Click here to see the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ieUzS.png)

And later on, when user clicks on one of these fragments, another fragment will be opened to display only that specific fragment.
Is this possible? Any recommendations would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: What does the ViewPager have to do with that? can you scroll all three to reveal 3 more on either side?

Comment: Not really, I thought I have to use it so I can show 3 fragments on the same Page. Can you tell me another way (maybe easier one) to achieve that? Thanks. I only have to display those 3 fragments in one page and handle on click event on them.

Comment: You can have nested fragments, or "child fragments" as described [by the docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/fragmentmanager#child).

Comment: And how can I customize the layout to show the Fragments as in the picture?

Comment: You can achieve that using ConstraintLayout in about 2 minutes if you're experienced. Your "Root" View is a CL (ConstraintLayout) that takes the whole screen (match_parent). Inside, you're going to have 3 children. Fragment 1 pins top to top of parent, start to start of parent, end to start of Fragment 2. Frag 2 pins top to top of parent, end to end of parent, start to end of Frag 1. Fragment 3 pins bottom to bottom of parent, start/end to the parents, and top to bottom of fragment 1 (for example). These are all FrameLayouts or the new FragmentContainers (version/api dependendent).

Comment: @MartinMarconcini I tried that but it is not looking the way I want, I have to give them height and width as match_parent? cause I tried it and it's not ok..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really takes 3 minutes.

You have to give each container/view/widget a `0dp` which means "match_constrains", in other words: your size will be determined by the constrains you have (after they have been ran by [the algorithm](https://constraints.cs.washington.edu/solvers/cassowary-tochi.pdf)).

In the following Layout there are three widgets (I used the "new" `FragmentContainerView` but they can be `FrameLayout` instances as well.

Notice in all three:

- width/height is set to `0dp` (aka: `match_constrains`)

Fragment one:

- Top to Top of Parent (top of the screen)
- Start to Start of Parent (left/start of the screen)
- End(right) to Start(left) of Fragment Two.
- Bottom to Top of Fragment Three.

Fragment Two:

- Top to Top of Parent (top of the screen)
- Start(left) to End(right) of Parent
- End(right) to End of Parent (right/end of the screen)
- Bottom to Top of Fragment Three.

Fragment Three:

- Top to bottom of Fragment One (here I chose Fragment One, but could have used "two" or even a guideline set at 50%, this is fine)
- Start and End both pointing to the respective parent (since we want FR3 to use all the available width)
- Bottom to Bottom of Parent (fragment three goes all the way down).

The result looks like this:

[image: Preview]

And here's the Layout.

[Now go and spend some time learning Constraint Layout. :)](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/widget/ConstraintLayout)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/fragment_one"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/fragment_two"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/fragment_three" />

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@id/fragment_two"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/fragment_one"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/fragment_three" />

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/fragment_three"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_purple"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/fragment_one"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I know how CL works but didn't know the part with height and width set to 0dp..